# Show why the proof for the following is false $u\mid mn$ and $\gcd(u,m) = 1$, then $m = \pm1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Let $u,m,n$ be three integers.

If $u\mid mn$ and $\gcd(u,m) = 1$, then $m = \pm 1.$

If $\gcd(u,m) = 1$, then $1 = us + mt$ for some integers $s, t$.

If $u \mid mn$, then
$us = mn$ for some integer s.

Hence, $1 = mn + mt = m(n + t)$, which
implies that $m|1$, and therefore $m = 1$.

First dips into discrete math and having trouble with proofs

I've been playing around with various values and found $u=2, m=3, n=4,$ to be a counterexample to the proof but have yet to find the flash of inspiration needed to understand why.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have used two different $s$, am I right? What is the guarantee  that they are the same? Only if they are the same can you perform that substitution. Otherwise, for clarity, $1=us_1+mt$ and $us_2=mn$ for some $s_1$ and $s_2$, which need not be the same, in which case you can't just replace the expressions!

Comment: from what i can tell there isn't any guarantee.

Comment: You are correct, there is no guarantee. The replacement can't be  done, and therefore the proof is incorrect. To go through it, you have  your counter example, which is $u=2,m=3,n=4$. Find $s_1$ and $s_2$, they shouldn't be the same!

Comment: hmm, okay well at least I know I'm falling off the right cliff now Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. As a tip, use different letters for different variables. Not only does it prevent mistakes like the one here, but it also makes questions clearer for others trying to answer your question.

Comment: Btw, what is correct is if $\,\gcd(u,m) = 1\,$ then $\,u\mid mn\,\Rightarrow\, u\mid n,\,$ which can be proved by scaling the Bezout equation $\, us + mt = 1\,$ by $\,n.\ $

Comment: If gcd(u,m) = 1, then 1 = us + mt for **some** integers s, t.... and .... If u|mn, then us = mn for **some** integer s.....  There is no reason to assumme those two uses of s are the same.  Look at this:  Proof that 0 = 160.  216 is even.  So 216 = 2n for some n.   57 is odd.  So 57 = 2n + 1 for some n.  But 2n = 216 so 57 = 2n + 1 = 216 + 1 = 217.  So 0 = 57 - 57 = 217 - 57 = 160.  QED.

Comment: By the way, the implication itself should be extremely suspicious: regardless of whether $\gcd(u,m)=1$ or $m=\pm1$, it's easy to choose $n$ such that $u\mid mn$ (take $n=u$ for example), so there's no reason to think that that hypothesis is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There exist integers $s ,t$ with $1=us+mt.$ There exists integer $s'$ with $us'=mn.$ IF $s=s'$ THEN $m=\pm 1.$ But if $s\ne s'$ then ... ?